# JMeter Not Sending Post parameter

Tags: django, post, jmeter

I have created a test for a Django web application on JMeter. I am making a post request to one of the views, but somehow when the length of the parameter is big (over 5000 characters) the post parameter is not sent. When I run the same test with a small length param it works fine.

Do anyone know why this may be the case? I was thinking maybe there is a limit on the param length in Jmeter, if this is the case, how can I increase it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone has the same problem, look at the value to see if there are any illegal characters that are submitted such as "%", or just use the encode option in Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such limit in JMeter. I have sent huge data as a parameter of the HTTP post request successfully.

What do you see in the **View Results Tree**?

1. Check if selecting/deselecting **Encode** for the parameter in **HTTP Request** works fine for you.
2. Ensure that the issue you are facing is not application related. (application might not accept parameters over 5000 chars)
3. Gradually increase the length and find when it exactly does not work & update this question with more details.

Comment: The result tree says it went through fine as that param is not "required", but when I look at the post params in the result tree it has that specific param blank. The application accepts long params. Thanks for the pointers, I will look into it and update.